# An explanation or hints to evaluate $\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}(x+\log (x))}{1-e^{-x}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-principal-value

After I was thinking how evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}x\log (x)dx$ (the idea is to differentiate an integral representation for $\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$ that holds for $\Re s>1$, and evaluating after at $s=2$), I was interested in the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}(x+\log (x))}{1-e^{-x}}dx.$$

Wolfram Alpha knows that is required to define the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) and find the result.

> **Question.** Can you explain and compute this integral/value 
>   $$\text{PV}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}(x+\log (x))}{1-e^{-x}}dx?$$

Many thanks. I want learn these calculations since there are different integrands of thse Cauchy principal values that could be interesting. **If you prefer only provide me hints, also you are welcome.**

Comment: the derivative of $x^{s-1}$ is $x^{s-1} \log(x)$. The integral you wrote diverges

Comment: Thaks @user1952009 the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}(x+\log (x))}{1-e^{-x}}dx$ diverges, but it is possible define PV, isn't ? Many thanks for your attention and patience (I say my last comment about what's a Euler product that I've deleted).

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I accept your words but Wolfram Alpha compute such [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-x)(x%2Blog(x))%2F(1-e%5E(-x))+dx,+from+x%3D0+to+infinite), or type *integrate e^(-x)(x+log(x))/(1-e^(-x)) dx, from x=0 to infinite* , in the online calculator @user1952009  When you refresh the code, it is calculated.

Comment: It is the same as $\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{x}dx$, it diverges, end of discussion.

Comment: OK or KO, well I wait if you or other user want clarify where was my mistake in comments. I take your notes @user1952009 thanks.

Comment: Your mistake is that you don't understand what you wrote, in particular the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value)

Comment: The existence of a PV depends on cancellations, e.g. between the positive and negative sides around 0 of 1/x to evaluate $PV\int \frac{1}{x} dx$.  Cauchy PV is completely irrelevant when considering the integral of a negative function such as $\log x / x$ over $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks @mathematician for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a course [on the convergence of integrals](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF) and the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) allowing us to say that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{x} = 0$ but it doesn't change that $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x} = \infty$

Also, WA should answer that it diverges, so maybe you have found a bug in WA, since in $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\frac{x+\log(x)}{1-e^{-x}}dx$ everything converges except $\int_0^1 e^{-x}\frac{\log(x)}{1-e^{-x}}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \log(x)(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x})dx$ where the second integral converges, so it reduces to

```
Integrate[Log[x]/x, {x, 0, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

where [WA answers - as wanted - that it diverges](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Blog(x)%2Fx,+%7Bx,+0,+1%7D,+PrincipalValue+-%3E+True%5D).

Comment: I accept your answer, I don't know what was about such calculation from the online calculator, then I was asking here. Many thanks.

Comment: @user243301 my answer won't help if you don't take 2 months reading a real analysis course, explaining in detail how to see if an integral (or a series) diverges or converges (see your other question)